# How can I obtain services to MongoDB Realm App?

Tags: mongodb, realm

Hi there fellow coders,

Maybe one of you could bridge the gap I seem to be having.

I'm new to Mongo and tried to set up a database. Then created a Realm App.

According to the documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/web/mongodb/), I need to link a data source(https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/link-a-data-source/).

Having done that, the doco seems to indicate I should be able to use the line:

```
const mongo = app.services.mongodb("<atlas service name>");
```

However, I get an error saying "Cannot read property 'mongodb' of undefined". Obviously, it's because there is no services against app.

I tried looking this up online, but found no answers. Hoping someone experienced could guide me as to what is missing or what I'm clearly not seeing.

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using MongoDB 4.4?

Are you using MongoDB Atlas? Realm sync does not work for on-premises MongoDB.

If you're using all that, I would go to https://realm.mongodb.com and click "Create a New App" and then the screen that shows up, you pick the cluster to connect with and that's the service. (or choose the 'we'll create one for you' option).

[image]

Comment: I have done all that you mentioned, but I noticed that my version is 4.2. Recreated the whole DB in version 4.4, but it made no difference. Still seeing the same error. Any other steps could cause this?

Comment: What service name did you use?

Answer (score 1):

**[Services are not included in realm-web code if it’s installed via npm](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/services-are-not-included-in-realm-web-code-if-its-installed-via-npm/10277)**

Services and functions are now available on User instance

```
const mongo = user.mongoClient("<atlas service name>");   
const db = mongo.db("<my-database-name>");
const collection = db.collection("<my-collection-name>");'
```

Answer (score 1):

The default name is mongodb-atlas:

const mongo = app.services.mongodb("mongodb-atlas");